# Jetbrains CLion [GCC linking]

Tags: c++, gcc, clion, jetbrains-ide

I have just install Jetbrains CLion IDE for C/C++ and it argues that it cannot find cmake compiler: [image: jetbrain clion]
I cannot find such tutorials on linking the compiler to the IDE even in the official website of Jetbrains. Also it says in the website that it supports gcc compiler and I do have that:[image]
I am really new in Linux world and it's very different than Windows(where I came from weeks ago) and I do really really want to use this IDE for my c++ programming, here is the CLions Toolchain settings: [image]
You can see that 'C++ Compiler: not found' in the Toolchains tab.

In the CMake tab this is what I have:[image]

Comment: Read [ask]. Also note that tags are not supposed to be in titles here on Stackoverflow. Then note that images are not searchable and try to include everything you can as text. Finally, note that asking for tutorials or any third-party resources is off-topic.

Comment: Try running `which gcc` in your terminal and get the path to the executable

Comment: CMake is not a compiler, but a tool to generate native build files. It is not installed by default on Debian/Ubuntu, use ```sudo apt-get install cmake``` and restart CLion. Alternatively you could use the bundled cmake, that comes with the IDE.

Comment: @JanHenke hello, I am using the bundled but it cannot find the c++, and I cannot see any settings in the CLion where I can give the location to the gcc(/usr/bin/gcc) which I got from the command 'which gcc' given by Dov Benyomin.

Comment: g++ is a separate binary in Debian based distributions. By default you only have gcc installed (the C compiler). You need to install ```g++```, the C++ compiler, by hand. ```sudo apt-get install g++```

Comment: @JanHenke, omg!! It worked! Thank you so much sir!!

Comment: @JanHenke, sir is there any way that whenever I compile this a terminal/console will pop up instead of just it will print the text in the bottom?

Comment: @Fur not that I am aware of. CLion is still pretty new, they are adding lots of features with every release. It might come later. I also converted my comment into a proper answer below, so other people finding this question find the correct answer easily. Would you mind accepting and up voting it, if it solves you problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To turn my comment into a proper answer.

The problem is the missing `g++` binary. In Debian based systems the different compiler front ends of `gcc` are packaged separately. Only `gcc`, the C compiler is installed by default.

So to use the C++ compiler (`g++`), one needs to install it by hand, there is a package of the same name.

```
sudo apt-get install g++
```

Takes care of everything, so you have a working C++ environment.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the needed tools:

**Run in Terminal:**

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install make
sudo apt-get install g++
```

Then restart the IDE and everything should run like a charm!

Comment: Hello sir, I am using the bundled from the CLion and as you can see it is checked in the picture but not the c++ compiler.

Comment: Hello sir, I ran those commands in my terminal and it says that I have the newest version of gcc and make :(